# Mathematical induction Divisibility proof Help [My proof does not match my teacher's solution]

Tags: induction, proof-explanation, solution-verification, divisibility

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6sW2.jpg

Synopsis: while proving $7$ divides $\,4^n-(-3)^n = : f(n)\,$ by induction on $\,n,\,$ my teacher and I got different expressions in the result of the induction step, namely

$\, f(k+1) = 7(4b+(-3)^k) \ $ by the teacher, vs.

$\, f(k+1) = 7(4^k - 3b) \ $ by me.

What did I do wrong?

I have spent 2 hours on this but don't know what I did wrong. I know my teacher worked it out differently but I want to know what error did I make on my solution because my teachers proof does not match mine.

thanks

Comment: Please use mathjax to edit your formulae.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with either proof.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: both are the same by $\ \overbrace{4^k\!-(-3)^k = \color{#c00}{4b + 3b}}^{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\large {\rm induction\ hypothesis}\ f(k)\, =\, \color{#c00}{7b}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}\, \Rightarrow\,\overbrace{4^k-3b}^{\large \rm you} = \overbrace{4b+(-3)^k}^{\large \rm teacher} $